# flex box not working how i wish for it to work

Tags: css

so having some problems with flex box, so maybe there is a different way of doing this?

I have five boxes on a row that stretch, but only 4 fit, so the last one is underneath, but it stretches so it fits the width of the page. I would like so that the elements that are bellow to be the same width as the one above it.

like so:

flex box:

[image]

what i want:

[image]

I need the webpage to be responsive so i would like to fit each row to the width of the screen, apart from when it wraps and it doesn't fit the row. so they are all the same width.

EDIT:my current code:

CSS:

```
.box-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-flow:wrap;
    align-items:flex-start;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.box {
    flex:300px 1 0;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="box-wrapper first-row">
     <div class="box"><img src="images/box.png" width="100%" /></div>
     <div class="box"><img src="images/box.png" width="100%" /></div>
     <div class="box"><img src="images/box.png" width="100%" /></div>
     <div class="box"><img src="images/box.png" width="100%" /></div>
     <div class="box"><img src="images/box.png" width="100%" /></div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the effect you are after is not possible without *actual* rows.

`flex-start` doesn't combine with `space-between` or `space-around` (AFAIK) so the closest you can get is:

```css
.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="box-wrapper first-row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hkbhq4tx/)

Comment: close, but yea, not desired effect. starting to think i might have to introduce some JavaScript to get what i want, flex box doesn't seem to have what i want in this case. actual rows i have played around with, but i would like to put everything on one row unless the resolution is to small.

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhek3pyu/)

```css
.box-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-flow:wrap;
    align-items:flex-start;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.box {
    background-color: red;
    height: 18vw;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 18vw;
    min-width: 100px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="box-wrapper first-row">
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
 </section>
```

The key here is that we don't use flex-grow for control the proportion, and instead outsource that responsibility to `vw`. Now we can use the flexbox for the wrapping behavior and the `vw` units to control the size.

Comment: That would mean that the first row would not fit the screen width and i would have a gap to the right on some resolutions. Not what i want in this case.

Comment: Can you further explain? You want large window sizes to see all 5 boxes, stretched to fit on 1 row, but smaller screen sizes to wrap? So at a certain threshold you want the boxes to not shrink but wrap?

Comment: yes, so on large resolutions the row will strecht to fit, then on smaller resolutions it will shrink, but the boxes have a min width of 300 so some boxes would have to wrap to the next row, but if it was just one or two boxes that wrap it would try and stretch and fit the whole row, which is not what i want, i would like the boxes to be the same width as the top boxes. like is the second image.

Comment: Could also just use flex-grow: initial;

Comment: this still has blank space to the right of the first row on some resolutions, same thing with flex-grow: initial unless im missing something. im starting to think the affect i have been wanting isn't possible with flex box system, maybe ill try fixing this with JavaScript. but if it is possible with flex box, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the minimum width to 300px (I set it to 100px to be able to see in the jsfiddle). Or do you always want the 5th box to be on a seperate row? If so, just create a new row, instead of doing it like this. Semantically, it's more logical at least for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/awfgqc0t/2/

```
.box-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items:flex-start;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.box {
    min-width: 100px;
    flex-grow: initial;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

EDIT:
What you're looking for is flex-grow: initial;